# How we can press Enter button in text-area by selenium python? (another way for submission)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, textarea, submit, enter

I want to send a text to a field and submit it. HTML code was shown. How should I do?
This is my HTML code:

```
<form class="_b6i0l"><textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea>
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea>
</form>
```

I want send a text to box with this code:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea._bilrf"), "nice!")
```

How can I press enter to send my text?
Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `send_keys()` (https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) and special keys module (https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.keys.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.keys)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
...
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea._bilrf").send_keys("nice!", Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea._bilrf").send_keys("nice!")
a.submit()
```